# To prove that $2^{3n}+2^n +1$ is not a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Question: Prove that $2^{3n} + 2^n + 1$ cannot be a perfect square for any natural $n$.

I attempted this question and failed in two different ways.

1) I considered a polynomial $p(x) = x^3+ x + 1 - m^2$ (for some natural $m$) and factorized the polynomial assuming $2^n$ is a root. I, then, tried substituting some numbers to get a contradiction in divisibility (since $x - 2^n$ is a factor). Alas, all of that was in vain.

2) I wrote $2^{3n} + 2^n + 1 = m^2$ and thus $(m-1)(m+1) = 2^n(2^{2n} + 1)$. So one can conclude that if $xy = 2^{2n} + 1$ such that $(x,y) = 1$, then one of the $m-1$ or $m+1$ must be $2^{n-1}x$ and the other must be $2y$ (this follows from the fact that $m$ is odd and $(m-1,m+1) = 2$). I am stuck at this point.

I would appreciate a hint in either direction. I am hoping that 1) will work out. It will teach me a new proofing (err... proving) technique.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm slightly amazed that this question got 15 up votes in 20 mins.

Comment: Can anyone confirm or deny that $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ is square if **and only if** $x=72$?

Comment: Would it help to consider the fact that any odd perfect square is equal to 1(mod 8)?

Comment: That only shows that $n \geq 3$

Comment: @AWalker: I am curious. How did you get to that proposition?

Comment: @Isomorphism I searched $f(x)$ for $x \leq 10^6$ and $x=72$ is the only square I've found.  I had hoped to find patterns indicating why $f(2^n)$ is never square (the proposition from my earlier comment would of course prove this).

Comment: @AWalker The only integral points on the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+x+1$ are $(x, y)=(0, \pm 1), (72, \pm 611)$.

Comment: @IvanLoh Is there an easy way to see this?  Unless I'm mistaken, the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+x+1$ has rank one, so I suppose it would be routine to look at ranks and determine all the integer points.  Is this what you did?

Comment: @AWalker Well, the amount of computation involved is actually non-trivial, if you try to do it by hand. The elliptic curve has rank $1$, and it has exactly one generator $(x, y)=(0, 1)$. Combine this with effective bounds and a brute force search, and you get all integer solutions. Or... you could just use a computer program like Sage and type E=EllipticCurve([1, 1]) and E.integral_points()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider 2 cases. If $n$ is odd, take $\pmod{3}$. If $n$ is even, bound between 2 squares.

Comment: +1 I should have read this simple soulution before startung my attempt.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan Loh. I knew the n odd case. But the even case idea was nice. Thanks again :)